# jQuery How to Animate Repeatadly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate the `#box` id repeatedly when I mouseover and mouseout it. However, It only animates the `#box` only at once for the first time. I have to refresh the page to animate again. How to fix it to make the animation continiously?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#757575");
        $(this).animate({
            bottom: "15px"
        }, 100);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#2C2C2C");
        $(this).animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Html</b>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
 <h1 id="box" class="box position-relative">Front-end Development</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , means html code to try out our solution...

Comment: Also bottom: and top does not do anything. Not sure what are trying to do.